# Is there an easy script which will display script 1 to US/ Canadian visitors and script 2 to the rest

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation, location, geo

I would like to know if there is an easy script which will display script 1 to US/ Canadian visitors and script 2 to the rest.

Does not need to be that accurate but using a service like http://freegeoip.net/json/18.8.8.82 is to complicated for me

Is there an easy way

a script example would greatly be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286827/php-whats-the-best-solution-to-check-a-users-country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try: [GEO Plugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/)

The PHP web service allows you to directly program your back-end PHP scripts to deliver dynamic geo-localized pages using the PHP array provided by geoPlugin.

[GEO Plugin PHP Web Service](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php)

It is easy to use.

**See Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/WktTV/